# Are these photinia's roots normal?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases

They've got an orangish colour, is it normal for this plant?

[image: Close-up of roots]

[image: Close-up of roots]

Answer (score 3):

White are new roots, yellow are older roots and dark brown are older less active roots.  Everything looks good with this plant!

You could repot it as I see a lot of roots at the bottom of the pot.  I would take a sharp knife and cut the bottom half inch of the root ball off.

Then, add fresh soil to the bottom and put the plant back in the same pot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't there some root rot going on though?  Looking at the top picture, the darker brown roots are kinda slimy and it also smells a bit weird.

Comment: @will yes, roots that don't smell good should be cut off.  That's why repotting and careful watering will help the plant

Comment: Slime spells too much watering.

Comment: I bought the plant online recently. It came with the soil quite wet, there was some hydrogel residue. Should I ask for a refund? Not sure how serious this is. Also would watering with diluted hydrogen peroxide help? I've found mixed opinions online.

Comment: @will There is not enough root rot to make it worth returning.  Peroxide is good for fungus gnats, not sure what the point is for dead roots.  Just give it lots of light and repot it and you are good to go